# Unix: using route to define route to a client

Tags: routing, lan

I got the following network topology:

client--monitor--controller--Internet

Earlier today I had to restart the controller and the client.Now I cannot ping the client from the controller anymore. All the other connections work fine, except this one.

The IPs are the following: 
client: 10.42.0.88 
monitor (connection to client): `10.42.0.1` (eth1) 
monitor (connection to controller): `10.42.1.72` (eth2) 
controller (connection to monitor): `10.42.1.1` (eth2) 
controller (connection to internet): `172.16.200.27` (eth0)

My routing tables are the following: 
Controller:
[image: Routing table at controller]

Monitor:
[image]

If I am at the monitor and ping 10.42.0.88 to reach the client, I would normally assume that the ping gets routed to the monitor and from there to the client.
The second rule directs the ping to the monitor via eth2. There it gets sent to the client (rule 2).

Interestingly when I do a `traceroute 10.42.0.88`, I get a timeout but the only displayed hop is `10.42.1.1` so I assume the problem is in the routing table of the monitor.

Pinging the controller from the client works without any problems.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so after some more trial&error I found the solution.
At the controller I provided the wrong gateway in the second line. Instead of 0.0.0.0 the gateway has to be `10.42.1.72`. From there the packet gets routed correctly.